# Cron task appears to run in syslog, but does not appear to be actually running

Tags: cron

I made a short script on one server to backup a folder and send it via FTP to another server. I'm trying to set it to run every minute using crontab. It works perfectly when I run it manually, but when cron runs it, nothing appears to happen (i.e. no file received on the other end). As I said in the title, the task shows up in syslog as if everything is A-OK.

Here's the script:

```
#! /bin/sh

cd /root

FILENAME="backup-$(date +%b_%d_%Y_%H:%M).zip"

zip -r $FILENAME folder

ftp -in 74.131.78.127 24721 << EOF > ~/log.txt 2>&1

user myusername 
binary
cd Desktop/backups
mput $FILENAME

EOF

rm $FILENAME
```

Crontab entry:

```
* * * * * /root/backup.sh
```

I entered this using `crontab -e`.

Comment: Are you prompted for a password when its run manually?

Comment: No, but it turned out to just be a permissions issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. The actual `root` did not have permissions to my ineptly named `/root` folder. A simple `chmod -R 707 /root` solved it.

Comment: You can also add the script to root's crontab `sudo crontab -e`and the job will run as root. This might be another way to get around your permissions problem.

Answer (score -1):

It is helpful to set up to create a separate cron.log, which is more useful.

This Q&A describes the process:

[16.04: How do I make cron create cron.log and monitor it in real time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time/966195#966195)

Also in this answer is the instructions to create a `wcron` command that displays it is near-real-time.

Plus, it links to another answer,

[How to change cron log level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949996/how-to-change-cron-log-level/)

that shows how to change the log level to include more than just the start of jobs - level 15 will show errors and end time, also.

Perhaps your answer is in the log output.